# Session values are null, why?

Tags: php, session, zend-framework, symfony

I have an old application running on top of Zend Framework 1 (ZF1), I'm starting a Symfony3 (SF) migration so I have managed with some `.htaccess` rules to make Symfony3 work inside the ZF1 application. Basically if I call a Symfony route it goes to Symfony controllers otherwise goes to ZF1 controllers.

I need to use ZF1 session data in the SF controller but the ZF1 Session and SF Session works completely in different way so calling ZF1 Session from the SF won't work. (I've already test it).

What comes to my mind then was save the same data to both session objects: the ZF1 used all over the legacy application and the SF used on the new controllers so I end up with something like this:

```
// The following goes to an special ZF1 storage managed through Session
$this->view->user = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
$result           = $this->view->user->getStorage()->read();

// This is a Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session
$session_1 = new Session(new PhpBridgeSessionStorage());
$session_1->start();
$session_1->set('result', $this->view->user->getStorage()->read());

// here $session_1 holds the values properly
$session_1->get('result');
```

The Symfony session is configured as follow:

```
session:
    handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
    save_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/sessions'
```

Then in my Symfony controller I am trying to access the stored data as:

```
$session = new Session();
$result = $session->get('result');
```

But the value of `$session->get('result')` is `null` and as far as I know it shouldn't be empty. I don't know if the directory structure is responsible for this issue or what I am doing wrong or maybe is simple and this is not possible at all because the `Session()` objects instances are different due to the directory structure.

This is how the directories are structured (weird but is the only way I did found so far to make this work):

```
├── application
│   ├── api
│   ├── controllers -> ZF1 controllers
│   ├── forms
│   ├── layout
│   ├── models
│   ├── soap
│   └── views
...
├── oneview_symfony -> this is the SF app
│   ├── app
...
│   ├── var
│   ├── vendor -> it has his own /vendor folder and a /symfony libraries
│   └── web
...
└── vendor
    ...
    ├── symfony -> /symfony libraries are here as well
    ...
    ├── zendframework
```

**Update**

Didn't tried before but now following @bishop suggestion I have bridged the Symfony session with ZF1 session (or at least I think I did) by adding the following:

```
session:
    storage_id: session.storage.php_bridge
    handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
    save_path: '%kernel.root_dir%/sessions'
```

But it doesn't work either, the error is same as before `result` gets `null`.

Any clues? Ideas?

Comment: Have you [bridged the Symfony session](http://symfony.com/doc/current/session/php_bridge.html) with your legacy ZF storage?

Comment: @bishop I didn't before but I have tried now and the result is the same, check the OP update

Comment: I'm not 100% confident that your session YML is being parsed. When you `new Session`, give it the session bridge per [these docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/session_php_bridge.html). Note also the use of `$session->start();`.

Comment: @bishop I have read that and fixed my code, check the OP again but sadly still not working maybe what's wrong is how I am reading the session on the Symfony controller? I am seeing the `sess_*` files created under `%kernel.root_dir%/sessions` but didn't contain the data I am storing I am not sure why

Comment: In an action in a controller, try: echo '<pre>' . print_r($_SESSION, 1) . '</pre>';     and see what it outputs. Maybe it's merging your session vars but putting them in indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @bishop and you correctly bridged the session, but I believe your problem is different. My assumption is that your session save_path is not shared between the Zend and Symfony applications.
You have to use the same path for this to work.
Try setting:

```
phpSettings.session.save_path = "/path/to/symfony/kernel/root/sessions"
```

in your application.ini of the Zend framework application. 
Replace with your sessions path.